# Setting console cursor and font color

Tags: c++, console-application

How can I set console cursor and its font color without including `windows.h`? is there any alternative way available?

Answer (score 5):

There is no platform-independent method for doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems you are using windows you can use the console calls

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685032(v=vs.85).aspx

alternatively you can use the old ANSI.SYS to color the text, but you would need to load the driver in config.sys for your console.

Comment: Those console calls are of course defined in `windows.h`, which the asker explicitly said he prefers not to include.